# how to add custom js to end of footer on every page

Tags: magento2, javascript, blocks, phtml

I want to add a custom js file to all pages before the footer
i want to pass script through phtml
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: It seems your question title and content doesn't match. You want to add after footer or before footer?

Answer (score 0):

call custom block and links in footer in magento 2

Create default.xml file

**app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/layout/defaul.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="custom_block" as="custom_block" template="custom.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Creat phtml file

**app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/templates/custom.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery","domReady!"], function ($) {
        //your js
    });
</script>
```

Don't forgot to clean cache !!

Comment: is this for everypage? i was looking at this <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
it didnt work for me but i will try yours

Comment: `before.body.end` it should also work.

Comment: didnt work for me, this is a custom module i am doing

Comment: Where are you putting these files? Send me the location with path

Comment: I have these following:
registration.php
composer.json
etc/module.xml
view\frontend\layout
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="custom_block" as="custom_block" template="integration.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
and templates

Comment: if i put this in  theme it works

Comment: That Sounds good

Comment: Do you also want this in module as well?

Comment: yes i am creating a new module to add new js

Comment: Are you sure, your new module is enabled?

Comment: Yes it is enabled, i have checked all that and its all enabled

Comment: any advice @DJ Dev

Comment: My above code should work for module. There is something wrong with your module. You will need to debug that !!!